# Stack Overflow occurs when controller is accessed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = db.Users.Include(u => u.Users1).Include(u => u.User1);
    return View(users.ToList());
}
```

Created an MVC / Entity project in Visual Studio, DB first.  Created two controllers, one named Users, the other named Tasks.  The page views for Tasks works fine but whenever I try to access the User view pages, I experience this stack overflow.

> Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2018-06-03T17:26:09.6757730Z","tags":{"ai.cloud.roleInstance":"DESKTOP-2V3VGT6","ai.operation.id":"lH/a0kZkKsE=","ai.operation.name":"GET Tasks/Index","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"web:2.5.1-195","ai.internal.nodeName":"DESKTOP-2V3VGT6"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"|lH/a0kZkKsE=.82dfa1d2_","name":"GET Tasks/Index","duration":"00:00:04.4166410","success":true,"responseCode":"200","url":"http://localhost:62166/Tasks","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Requests', Ver:'1.0')"}}}}
>       An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

```
The program '[7192] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

Full trace at:
https://pastebin.com/raw/846WTUqE

Comment: Why do you have the same `Include` twice?

Comment: the code I posted is what the MVC template generated.

Answer (score -2):

First remove the second include statement and see what the error is after that. If that doesnt work you could try a Select Where expression like this.  Add the ToList() to the variable and not the return.  Moving the ToList() wont make a different but makes it easier to debug.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = db.Users.Select().Where(u => u.Users1).ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
```

Comment: That will not even compile as there is no overload for `Select` that takes no arguments and unless `Users1` is a `bool` that lambda function will not match the `Func<T, bool>` that is required by `Where`.